# Editing a texture

Tags: texturing

I have downloaded [this rigged hand](https://free3d.com/3d-model/rigged-hands-28855.html) and I am successfully manipulating the fingers using a Python script and rendering still images to .PNG files. Perfect!

But I was hoping that if I edit `textures/HAND_C.JPG` (let's say I wanted a black hand, or purple nail varnish, or whatever) in Gimp and overwrote the file, then the edits would turn up whenever I launch Blender. It turns out that when I open `Rigged Hand.blend`, no difference in the appearance of the hand.

Is the texture somehow stored inside the `.blend` file? If so, how can I replace it with whatever I do to the JPG?

Comment: To be clear yes, updating an image file used as texture with an external editing application should update automatically in Blender. If that didn't happen then Blender might be using a packed version of that file, as brasshat mentions in his answer. Manually pointing Blender to the edited file and/or pressing the refresh button should solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Blender can store textures inside the Blend file, in a process called "packing", accessed through the file menu under the menu item "external data". Frankly, I would rather expect that on a downloaded file, that the image would be packed.

There may be a way to edit the image, and have the edited image used instead, but the exact procedure might depend upon whether the model uses the Blender internal render (BI), or cycles, and it appears to me that Cycles might be the rendering engine of choice, and that is presently outside my skillset.

Comment: When I choose `Unpack all into files` from that `External Data` menu, then I get "no files to unpack" error. I take it to mean that Blender must be reading the texture from an external file. Yet, even after closing blender and opening it again, the texture is the same as it was before I edited it...